# send value from jquery drop down list tp separate ajax function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i wanna send a value from  drop down list to a separate ajax function

here is some of my code that i use for the drop down list used with materializecss

```
        <a class='dropdown-button btn' href='#' data-activates='dropdown1'>choisir le temp d'arrivée !</a>


<ul id='dropdown1' class='dropdown-content'>
<li><a href="#!">5 minutes</a></li>
<li><a href="#!">10 minutes</a></li>
<li><a href="#!">15 minutes</a></li>
```

and the ajax function

```
     function isochroneIGN(lat, lng) {
    var urlign = 'http://wxs.ign.fr/rvahvdprhlyejxbib0gemjzn/isochrone/isochrone.json';
    $.ajax({
      url: urlign,
      data: {
        location: lng+','+lat,
        method: 'Time',
        graph: 'Pieton',
        graphName: 'Pieton',
        exclusions: '',
        time: 5000,
        holes: true,
        smoothing: true
      },
      type: 'GET',
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(res) {
        layerGroup.clearLayers();
        var wkt = new Wkt.Wkt();
        wkt.read(res['wktGeometry']);
        var feature = wkt.toObject();
        feature.setStyle({
          color: '#FF0000',
          fill: true,
          fillColor: '#FF0000',
          fillOpacity: 0.2
        });
        layerGroup.addLayer(feature);
        map.fitBounds(layerGroup.getBounds());
      },
      error: function(res) {
        console.log(res);
      }
    })
  }
```

i want to send the value of the jquery drop down list to time variable

thanks for help ,

Comment: which dropdown is this?. it must be coming with an onchange function

Comment: it s materialize drop down list that should send values to ajax function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// manually bind the value
$('#dropdown1 li').click(function(){

   $('#dropdown1').attr('data-val', $(this).attr('value'));
})
//    and use it as
 $.ajax{ ..... 
   time: $('#dropdown1').attr('data-val')
  }
```